# React useMemo hook use case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### Context

After reading through the official doc for hooks, I wanted to try [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) in one of my projects.

To test it, I set up a sandbox project [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/suspicious-pine-4z1xq).

The example uses an **expensive computation** at every input change (see "**ellapsed** ms"). Every time this expensive computation runs, a counter gets incremented (see "**counter**").

Example is perfect for [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) so I use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook, but the results were not what I expected, leading me to believe I have misunderstood something fundamentally here.

---

### Expected:

- **first render slow**: computation && counter incrementation of a value
- **Rerenders** near instant computation with no counter incrementation

---

### Actual:

Slow computation each time && counter increments each time, despite same input.

[image: useMemo_example]

Again, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-pine-4z1xq) is the link to the project. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useMemo` gets triggered every time the value changes because you add it with `[value]` as the second parameter. That is why inserting a new value into the input leads to a new computation. `useMemo` is used to prevent unnecessary calculations, if something else, but not value, changes. But since the only thing that can change is your value, you see the calculation done every time. If the component has more state/prop values, you would see that the computation will be skipped, if these other state/prop values change. Hope this makes it clearer. Happy coding.

Comment: So to be clear, it doesn't use memoization based on the [value], but to the contrary it ignores all changes except those on [value]. Now that you explained it, it's just like useEffect's deps variable. Makes sense

Comment: Yes exactly, on every render, it will check if value changed. If it did, the computation will be triggered. If not, it will return the previous calculated value,